# Syncing two domain user accounts with one password on windows 10

Tags: security, microsoft-outlook, user-accounts

I'm looking to see if this is possible:

We have a dozen of high priority users that get two domain user accounts, lets call the first one a regular account which they use to login and do every day work. The second account lets call it the private account is used specifically to have a second exchange mailbox. They don't login into the private account unless they are changing their password after the time period is up.

On the regular account in outlook we add the additional private account mailbox, so they can view both their regular account email and private account email side by side. They never log into the private account except to change their password.

Is it possible to have the private account password sync with the regular account password, so they do not have to manually change both passwords when the time period is up?

To summarize,

two separate domain accounts, the second accounts sole purpose is for an additional mailbox which is added in outlook on the regular account. Would it be possible to sync these account so that when the regular account password is changed it changes the private account password.

Comment: Not that I know of. But, have you run in to the obstacle of accessing these secondary mailboxes on mobile devices yet? It is another hurdle. One solution to your problem is to disable the password change policy for those second accounts. Think about it, if the second account is setup with a complex, random, and unknown password that users never login with then there is zero reason to force a change periodically.

Answer (score 0):

You could let the secondary domain admin set a group policy, to make the second accounts' passwords never expires.

[image]